# delete rows in matrix in conditions in matlab

Tags: matlab, conditional-statements, rows

My program creates a matrix whose cell values ​​in multiple rows are the same in the corresponding column. I want to delete some rows that have 0 more than one. To clarify, my matrix has the following form,

A=[ 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1; 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1; 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0; 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1
1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 ]

and I want to delete all the columns that are in the first, second and fifth rows because the number 0 is 2
or more left in the matrix of rows that are in the third and fourth rows because they have 0 one in each row.
The result should be the following matrix:

A=[ 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0; 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 ]

Comment: Your input matrix has a different number of values in each row, it is not a matrix, and that line of MATLAB code would produce an error if I tried to run it. Then you say you want to delete columns, but your desired output has fewer rows than the input. I’m baffled and don’t at all understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

i write this code for your algorithm than work correctly:

```
% Input Matrix
A = [1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1;1 0 0 1 1  1 1 1; 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0;1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1;1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 ];

% find number of rows and cols
[num_rows, num_cols] = size(A);

% Itrate on each row and find rows that have less than 2 zeros
selected_rows = [];
idx = 1;
for i=1:num_rows
    num_zero = sum(A(i, 1:end) == 0);
    if num_zero < 2
        selected_rows(idx) = i;
        idx = idx+1;
    end
end

% return result matrix
result = [];
for i=1:length(selected_rows)
    result = [result; A(selected_rows(i), 1:end)];
end

disp(result)
```